# Override ON_CALL default action in Insequence EXPECT_CALL

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I want to override the ON_CALL default action only in one of my test case.
But I couldn't get the result I want.

According to gMock Cookbook, it mentions that  ON_CALL default action can be replaced if there is a matching EXPECT_CALL.
[gMock Cookbook ON_CALL](http://google.github.io/googletest/reference/mocking.html#ON_CALL.WillByDefault)

However, it seems not working to override it in the Insequence clause.

```
void SetUp()
{
    ON_CALL(mock, GetNumofChild()).WillByDefault((Return(2));
    /*other on_call defaults*/
}

TEST_F(Testing, TestGetValue){
    {
        testing::InSequence seq;

         /*  other expect_call  */
        EXPECT_CALL(mock, GetNumofChild()).WillOnce((Return(10));
        /*  other expect_call  */
    }

    Foo();
}
```

During runtime

```
   uint8 u8NumOfChild = m_obj.GetNumofChild();    
   // Result: u8NumOfChild equal to 2, result by ON_CALL
   // Expected: u8NumOfChild equal to 10, overridden by EXPECT_CALL
```

Comment: Can't reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/37MGxar75 Please [edit] the question and post a [mcve].

Comment: Huhh.. you are right. It works as expected in the external complier your provided.
I think is due to the production code I'm testing. It's much more complex than the example I provided here.
Weirdly, I was able to get the expect_call work if it is outside the Insequence clause.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question since I found the root cause to it.

Since the EXPECT_CALLs is in sequence, the previous sequential EXPECT_CALL is not satisfied. Hence the "expected" EXPECT_CALL is not called, instead the ON_CALL default action is called.

```
TEST_F(Testing, TestGetValue){
    {
        testing::InSequence seq;

         /*  other expect_call  */ <-- Not fulfilled
        EXPECT_CALL(mock, GetNumofChild()).WillOnce((Return(10));
        /*  other expect_call  */
    }

    Foo();
}
```